# Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) version confusion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vsto

Can someone enlight me about the version bindings between VSTO and the targeted office version?

I am using VS2008 with VSTO 3.0 to build and deploy an addin for Outlook 2003. I am totally confused about what is required on the target machine:

VSTO 2005 SE runtime or VSTO 3.0 runtime?

.NET Framework 2.0 or 3.5

Primary Interop Assemblies from Office 2003 (I guess)

In the end I need to tell the IT department of the customer how to deploy the addin using their own script based deloyment system. They do not want to have an MSI package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the [VSTO 3.0 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=54EB3A5A-0E52-40F9-A2D1-EECD7A092DCB&displaylang=en) for Office 2007 and the [VSTO 2005 SE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8315654B-A5AE-4108-B7FC-186402563F2B&displaylang=en) for Office 2003.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) has a good table of what links with what.

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia link, I must have missed this until now. But this states, that my environment is built against the 2005 SE runtime - will both work?

Comment: you are correct, misremembered how it worked. Have corrected. For 03 you need to use the VSTO 05 SE runtime.

Comment: VSTO 2005 SE runtime worked, .net 2.0 is sufficient, but it requires to set the target framework in the addin project correctly.